# FTP Upload image

Tags: c#, ftp

I was wondering what is wrong with this code? Im hosting a ftp on 000webhost and i want to upload a image that the user on my program opens from there computer using the openfiledialog feature

The Button to open image:

```
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = bit;
            pictureBox2.Image = bit;
            bit.Dispose();
            string fullPath = open.FileName;
            string fileName = open.SafeFileName;
            string path = fullPath.Replace(fileName, "");
            User.Details.UpLoadImage(fullPath);
        }
```

The code to upload it:

```
try
        {
            String sourcefilepath = source; // e.g. “d:/test.docx”
            String ftpurl = "ftp://www.locu.site90.com/public_html/"; // e.g. ftp://serverip/foldername/foldername
            String ftpusername = "********"; // e.g. username
            String ftppassword = "********"; // e.g. password
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(source);
            string ftpfullpath = ftpurl;
            FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
            ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

            ftp.KeepAlive = true;
            ftp.UseBinary = true;
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(source);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();

            Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
            ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ftpstream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I keep getting some errrors
"The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command"
and the second error is
"The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in .”

Comment: Maybe the server requires a secure connection (ssl), ftp.EnableSSL = true.

Comment: And how can that be solved?

Comment: Improper url can be solved by changing the url to include the filename at the end ex: String ftpurl = "ftp://www.locu.site90.com/public_html/test.txt"; You might of intended to do string ftpfullpath = ftpurl+filename;?

Comment: And what would the file name be? I just want to upload the image to the website? What is the file all about

Comment: Anything you upload to a server requires a file name. You can name it whatever you want, just know it has to be unique/folder. If it is an image, for testing purpose name it test.[whatever extension the image file is]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing an upload. The destination file name is required in the FTP url. It looks like that is what you might of intended to do with the following line:

```
string ftpfullpath = ftpurl;
```

Try changing it to:

```
string ftpfullpath = ftpurl + filename;
```

For the not logged in error, some hosting companies only allow secure connections. You can try adding the following line to your code:

```
ftp.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Hi. I did your code that fixed my first error. I'm now receving the second error - An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in App.exe

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.

Comment: are you sure the credentials are correct? i would use something like filezilla and make sure you can connect via tool first. Then once that works. then try coding it.

Comment: I did your enableSsl fix and it fixed. Have you any idea why it is now throwing me this error? - An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in App.exe

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized.

Comment: That error is quite generic. It could mean you have a firewall or something blocking something or it can mean that SSL is not supported on the server.

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: i would call your hosting company and see what requirements they have for this and what security is required and what method of authentication. And are you sure you are using the correct username, some times the user name might be "username" but it requires it in the form of an email address.

Comment: I have tested my details on FileZilla and works perfectly with the ones in the coding. And I went to the url in a browser and I logged in correctly and successfully. And im still receiving the command unrecognized error

Answer (score 0):

I am using this method, and that is working well:

```
public static void UpLoadImage(string image, string targeturl)
        {
            FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.website.com/images/" + targeturl);
            req.UseBinary = true;
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
            byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(image);
            req.ContentLength = fileData.Length;
            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
        }
```